# how do i print out every other character from a string in C?

Tags: c, string

simplest way to print out every other character from a string in C? I already tried to loop through the array using

```
int main (void) 


for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i+=2)
{
    word[i] += input[i];
}
```

Comment: move `strlen(p)` out of the loop, otherwise it'll be called again and again each iteration

Comment: You have background in other languages, don't you? I recommend https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ E.g. by the following steps: 1) Find a HelloWorld in C and make it run 2) change it to print character by character. 3) Change to increment the position by 2 instead of 1

Comment: @phuclv In theory yes. And compilers did that back in the days. Nowadays the compiler should be able to tell that `input` is not changed by the loop and that no pointers in the loop are aliases, so that the compiler only needs to evaluate the strlen expression once.

Comment: @Lundin no, [most compilers won't optimize that](https://godbolt.org/z/1Ofuqm) and still call the function again in every loop

Comment: @Lundin, this will only work with some known functions. Otherwise the compiler cannot know whether the return value might change in each iteration..

Comment: @Gerhardh Indeed. Or unless the compiler inlines the function call, in which case it will know perfectly well.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you just print it inside the loop?

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i+=2)
{
    putchar(input[i]);
}
```

If you want to copy only each 2nd char into another array, your mistake is using the same index `word[i] += input[i];`

*and as @bcperth mentioned, also using the += operator instead of a regular assignment `'='`*

What you should have done is:

`word[i/2] = input[i];`

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char* p = "hello world";
    char s[32] = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(p); i+=2){
        putchar(p[i]);
        s[i/2]=p[i];
    }

    printf("\n\n2nd option\n%s", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
hlowrd

2nd option
hlowrd
```

Comment: worth to note, that the target string size is limited to 32 bytes, this means that input buffer larger than 63 characters will crash the program.
note also that strlen(p) is evaluated at every for loop, and is actually constant. so it is better getting this value before the for loop and use it as constant.